# Is my PDO INSERT INTO enough secure?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, code-injection

I would like your opinion about my code. Is it secure enough against any injections.
Thanks for your replies.

```
class Product extends DB {

  public function __construct() {
    $db = $this->DB();

    if(isset($_POST['productName'])) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
                $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);
                $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
        }
        $this->AddProduct();
    }
  }

  public function AddProduct() {
    $sSQL = "INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."product (productName, productPrice) 
                VALUES (:productName,:productPrice)";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sSQL);
    $query->execute(array(
        ":productName" => $_POST['productName'],
        ":productPrice" => $_POST['productPrice']
    )); 
  }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be correctly using parameterized queries and thus would be protected against SQL injection (barring bugs in PDO itself).

Answer (score 3):

Using query parameters is enough to make it secure against SQL injection vulnerability.

The code that calls htmlspecialchars and strip_tags is not relevant to SQL injection. It might be called for to prevent Cross-Site Scripting vulnerabilities, but that's a separate issue. I don't recommend doing those steps as you insert data into the database. Just filter against XSS vulnerabilities when you output to HTML. Otherwise, you get literal `&amp;` sequences stored in your database, and that's premature. You aren't necessarily going to use the data to display in HTML every time. Just encode it when you output, not when you input.

I never bother with compensating for the possible magic_quotes_gpc. Test for it when you deploy your app, and abort the deployment. It's not valid for *any* PHP instance to set magic_quotes_gpc in 2014.

Comment: Thank you for your clever reply. magic_quotes_gpc is set on because I'm on a local machine but I understand your remark. However, about a JS injection for example, I don't understand why you recommend to do not a strip_tags before insert data into the database. I will have JS code in my database then?

Comment: "I will have JS code in my database then?" Yes, and that's fine. You should be dealing with such things on the display end, not the insertion side. This prevents situations where your escaping might have unexpected results - if you escape on insert, you've lost the user's original submission. If you escape on output, you can adjust escaping on-the-fly and have it always work.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now, you've right. I'll try to be less focused in the future on the "beauty" of my database :) Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: A database that actually stores the input _is_ beauty, storing HTML(-safe) presentations of that data is something for caching mechanisms ;)

Comment: I agree completely with @Wrikken. That was well-stated.